# Updating arrays in React as soon as fetched data from api changes

Tags: reactjs

In my React App I am using useEffect to fetch data from api :

```
const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('api_link').then((result) => {
      result.json().then((resp) => {
        setData(resp);
        setLoading(false)
      })
    })
  }, [Data])
```

My react app just shows a better visual representation of the fetched data and I want to update the data on my app as soon as it changes in api data.
Here the data that api_link provides changes every 2-3 seconds. I guess on using [Data] as dependency it is updating in my app whenever data is changing from fetched data in API.

Now on other functionalities on my app like search I am using:

```
const handleSearch = (searchedTerm) => {
    setsearchTerm(searchedTerm);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      const filteredCrypto = Object.entries(Data).filter(
        ([key, obj]) => obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())).map((item) => item[1]);

      setSearchResults(filteredCrypto)
  }, [searchTerm])
```

This `searchResults` I send to another component. Now what I am facing is that in those search results the data does not update and that must be because the searchResults is just an array which is not updating. So my question is How do I update the data in such cases whenever the data fetched from api changes so as to reflect in other components.

Comment: 1) This screams infinite rerender with changing the dependancy in the useEffect. 2) "How do I update the data in such cases whenever the data fetched from api changes so as to reflect in other components." By passing the `data` to those other components via props.

Comment: Can you explain 1? I am passing these arrays as props to other components but the data in those arrays does not update